# How can I prevent controller methods from running twice in spring boot in chrome browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot with postgresql to save row in table and print table rows. My problem is that all the WebController methods are being executed twice but only when I open the url in chrome. If I do this in internet explorer, it works fine. How can I stop this in chrome?

I am putting the code of four files for the reference although I don't think anything's wrong in the code. Do I need to change browser settings or something?

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("User[id=%d, name='%s', email='%s']",this.id,this.name,this.email);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

WebController.java

```
@RestController 
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("whaaat");
        return "hi";
    }

    @GetMapping("/save")
    public String process() {

        repository.save(new User("vidhi","vd@gmail.com"));
        System.out.print("apple ");
        return "Done";
    }

    @RequestMapping("findall")
    public String findAll() {
        String result = "";

        for(User u: repository.findAll()) {
            result += u.toString() + "<br>";
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password= 
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```

I got to know that the methods are running twice because of double addition of rows in the table and "whaaat" is printed twice in console but only when in chrome.
Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First. Try "Network" tab in Chrome Developer Tools (try F12 button) to identify how many requests are actually sent.
[image]

Second.
It's generally not a good idea to save any data at "GET" request, because of it's semantic, browser doesn't expect changes on server side and can invoke request multiple times (can't produce a use case for that, but it's totally not forbiden for browser to do that) or get it from cache.

Comment: Browser can make request retransmission for POST request either, but your remark is correct anyway